# Graphics tool for extracting snapshots from a video for Linux

Tags: linux, video, image-processing

I am looking for a graphics tool that can extract snapshots from a video, and one that I have come across is [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/), described in a response to  [What free tool can step through and extract individual frames of a video?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/237/what-free-tool-can-step-through-and-extract-individual-frames-of-a-video).

Is there something similar available for Linux?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185877/how-to-extract-images-from-video-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What free tool can step through and extract individual frames of a video?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/237/what-free-tool-can-step-through-and-extract-individual-frames-of-a-video)

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate. The linked question doesn't specify the OS at all – and here the OP asks specifically for Linux. OP explicitly pointed that out, and even linked to that other question.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a graphic tool but a media player and it will do the job I think.

You could use the old good and always there for you [VLC](http://www.videolan.org). It allows you to set up and configure batch frame extraction.

Please take a look at this [guide](https://turbofuture.com/computers/How-to-take-batch-screenshots-or-screencaps-in-VLC-Media-Player),  with a few changes it should work for Linux.